Unable to completely isolate two PM2 installations on Windows
I am using PM2 (Node Process Manager) on Windows and need to run two separate PM2 installations at the same time (both in cluster mode).
I have two completely separated (isolated) installation directories which have their own:

node installation
pm2 installation
PATH environment variable
PM2_HOME environment variable

BTW: the installation directories are portable, so no shared files or registry keys etc.
When I start only one PM2 instance, all works fine (the child worker instances are attached to the node process which runs PM2). This works well for both installations.
However, if I start both PM2 instances (one after the other, no matter in which order), the second one starts the correct (second) node process for PM2, but then attaches the child worker instances to the node process of the first PM2 installation.
Is this a bug in PM2 for Windows or do I miss something?
How exactly does the second PM2 instance identify the already running node process from the first installation and how can I avoid it so that both PM2 processes run separately with their own child worker instances?
Thanks for your help.

Found the solution, PM2 has a bug in it's source file paths.js when running under Windows (unique in-memory named pipes to identify the socket of an already running daemon even if separated PM2_HOME environment variables are used). They even have a todo comment that they should fix it...
Current Code:
if (process.platform === 'win32' ||
    process.platform === 'win64') {
  //@todo instead of static unique rpc/pub file custom with PM2_HOME or UID
  pm2_file_stucture.DAEMON_RPC_PORT = '\\\\.\\pipe\\rpc.sock';
  pm2_file_stucture.DAEMON_PUB_PORT = '\\\\.\\pipe\\pub.sock';
  pm2_file_stucture.INTERACTOR_RPC_PORT = '\\\\.\\pipe\\interactor.sock';
}

Fixed Code (just one possible way to fix it):
if (process.platform === 'win32' ||
    process.platform === 'win64') {
  //@todo instead of static unique rpc/pub file custom with PM2_HOME or UID
  pm2_file_stucture.DAEMON_RPC_PORT = '\\\\.\\pipe\\' + process.env['PM2_HOME'] + '\\rpc.sock';
  pm2_file_stucture.DAEMON_PUB_PORT = '\\\\.\\pipe\\' + process.env['PM2_HOME'] + '\\pub.sock';
  pm2_file_stucture.INTERACTOR_RPC_PORT = '\\\\.\\pipe\\' + process.env['PM2_HOME'] + '\\interactor.sock';
}

I also found this reported issue: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5212

Why do you need launching two PM2 instance?
PM2 can start process with different node version.
See my response to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73266114/8807231
